# Are cockpits waterproof to prevent spills

Tags: cockpit

Are cockpits waterproof, i.e. designed with the fact that a pilot might spill  a hot or cold drink over the instruments by mistake?

Comment: Minor nit, but a waterproof instrument panel (say) wouldn't *prevent* spills in the cockpit. The risk of spills is unchanged by whether the instrument panel is waterproof or not. What changes is the consequences of a spill. If anything, if everything is waterproof that might make pilots and others in the cockpit be *less* careful, because they know that the consequences are likely to be less severe.

Comment: *Fate is the Hunter*?